# It is not possible to make a request to the server over a unix socket using aiohttp

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception, post, aiohttp

I'm trying to make a POST request to a `unix socket` using `aiohttp`, but the following error occurs:

```
await client.post('/test',   File ".../test/env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client.py", line 508, in _request     
req = self._request_class(   File ".../env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 305, in __init__     self.update_host(url)   
File ".../env/lib/python3.9/site-packages/aiohttp/client_reqrep.py", line 364, in update_host     
raise InvalidURL(url) aiohttp.client_exceptions.InvalidURL: /test
```

code:

```
async with ClientSession(connector=UnixConnector(path='.../server.sock')) as client:
    response = await client.post('/test')
```

Answer (score 1):

`'/test'` is not an absolute URL.

Try something like `'http://fake.org/test'` instead.

Comment: That is, the host in the full address will be ignored if the unix socket connector is used?

Comment: It is still present in the sense of HTTP protocol but it is not used for selecting UNIX socket address to connect to.